# Issue with a for loop (C++, Visual Studio

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have only really been coding for a few days, though I've reading the textbook for my Intro to C++ class for two weeks. I'm having an issue with an assignment, and I feel like I'm missing something super simple, but I can't understand what I've done wrong.

The exercise calls for you to 'write a program that reads numbers from cin, and then sums them, stopping when 0 has been entered.'

The professor told us we could write it with a for loop, a while loop, or a do-while loop. I am trying to write it with a for loop.

The program compiles successfully, it allows me to enter multiple values, and it sums it correctly. It also stops on no successfully. The only thing that's wrong with it is when I enter 0, it does not stop the program. I have tried using different commands inside the for loop, such as goto, and trying to direct it to go to break; when the value entered is zero, but my knowledge is shoddy, to say the least. I've read the textbook but I don't have enough experience yet, and I don't remember everything, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is what the program looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()

{
    char indicator{ 'n' };
    double value{};
    double sum{};


    for (;;)
    {

        cout << endl
            << "Enter a value here: ";
            cin >> value;
        sum += value;
        cout << endl
            << "Do you want to enter another value (enter y or n)? ";
            cin >> indicator;
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;


    }

    cout << endl
        << "The sum of the values you entered is " << sum << "."
        << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Please point out my stupid mistake, I'd be grateful to learn. Thank you!

Comment: OP your code is copied almost word for word from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147277(v=vs.88).aspx

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby how to found it?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz I'm not sure what you're asking.. I apologize

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby I apologize to asking inaudible questions. It was interesting to me how you find the code come from? :)

Comment: @sorosh_sabz ohhh okay, I just copied out a portion of the code and googled it, its taken directly from an MSDN example in that link (Ex3_10.cpp) to be exact, same variables, spacing, etc. Just removed the comments, basically

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby :D thanks

Comment: @ConfusedCollegeStudent I would certainly suggest re-evaluating what you've presented here. If I can figure out its copied code in 2 minutes on google, I'm sure your professor would be able to do the same..

Answer (score 2):

There is no sense to ask the user each time whether he wants to continue.

So I would write the loop the following way

```
cout << "Enter a sequence of real numbers (0 - exit): "; 
for (;;)
{
    if ( !( cin >> value ) || ( value == 0.0 ) ) break;
    sum += value;
}
```

Also as the variable `value` is used only in the body of the loop it should be declared there. So the loop can look like

```
cout << "Enter a sequence of real numbers (0 - exit): "; 
for (;;)
{
    double value;

    if ( !( cin >> value ) || ( value == 0.0 ) ) break;

    sum += value;
}
```

An alternative for this for loop is while loop of the following form

```
cout << "Enter a sequence of real numbers (0 - exit): "; 
while ( true )
{
    double value;

    if ( !( cin >> value ) || ( value == 0.0 ) ) break;

    sum += value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compare `value` to zero after it is inputted:

```
for (;;)
{

    cout << endl
        << "Enter a value here; enter 0 to stop: ";
        cin >> value;
   if(value==0.0) break;
   sum += value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to make a few suggestions to you which you may find helpful.

To begin, any of the loops you mentioned (`for`, `while`, `do while`) may be used in solving this problem. But I believe that the `do while` lends itself best to this particular problem.

The use of a `for` is especially bad for this exercise as `for` loops are typically employed while performing iterations over a set of values or some sort of finite counting. Being asked to perform an action an indefinite number of times is better suited for a `while` or `do while`.

Just look at your `for` declaration:

```
for(;;)
{
    // ...
}
```

What benefit does using `for` have in this situation if you make use of none of it's functionality.

Second, the use of `double` is for your `value` and `sum` is not recommended either. This is because of something called floating-point precision. You can not reliably compare a `double` value using `==`. See: [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Instead, unless specified by the problem statement, I would opt to use an integer value type. Either `int` or `unsigned int`.

Third, you are not correctly initializing your variables. Instead, it should be done as:

```
int value = 0;
int sum = 0;
```

Improper variable initialization can lead to countless bugs and is a very common source of problems.

Finally, I would recommend against the use of `using namespace`. This is used commonly by beginner developers who then are taught better practices and then have to unlearn the behavior. See: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Taking this advice into consideration would lead to a solution such as:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int sum   = 0;
    int value = 0;

    do
    {
        sum += value;
        std::cout << "Please enter a value: ";
        std::cin >> value;
    } while(value != 0);

    std::cout << "The sum of all values entered is: " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change

```
cout << endl
        << "Do you want to enter another value (enter y or n)? ";
cin >> indicator;
if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
    break;
```

with

```
cout << endl
        << "Do you want to enter another value (enter 0 for exit or not zero to continue)? ";
int indicator = -1;
cin >> indicator;
if (indicator == 0)
     break;
```

If you do not want to ask user to continue enter new value in every time @Govind Parmar and @Vlad from Moscow write cleaner code than you write.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. You're not going to believe me, but I didn't mean to cheat. Is it cheating, for example, if I take half of someone's code and change it, or just twenty five percent? Ten percent? Thank you, especially, ssell, for your answer, because I think you explained it the best.

Comment: Anyway, I will try my best to rewrite it using a different version, and not one on here, either. I have read my textbook, but it's just hard to understand at this point. I think I might have to go over everything again, even though I've already read it. Anyway, thanks for the help! Like I said, I wasn't trying to cheat (not that you'll believe me) but thanks for answering my question anyway. I think it would be best for me to go over data types and the loop chapter again. Thanks again!

Comment: @ConfusedCollegeStudent that's ok, best regards you :)